# Pyspark conditional function evaluation based on another column

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a sample data set like below

```
sample_data = [('A', 'Chetna', 5, 'date_add(date_format(current_date(), \'yyyy-MM-dd\'), 7)'), 
           ('B', 'Tanmay', 6, '`date_add(date_format(current_date(), \'yyyy-MM-dd\'), 1)`'),
           ('C', 'CC', 2, '`date_add(date_format(current_date(), \'yyyy-MM-dd\'), 3)`'), 
           ('D', 'TC', 9, '`date_add(date_format(current_date(), \'yyyy-MM-dd\'), 5)`')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(sample_data, ['id', 'name', 'days', 'applyMe'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df = df.withColumn("salary", lit('days * 60'))
```

I am trying to evaluate the function provided in `applyMe` column and `salary`.
So far have tried doing it with `expr` and `eval` but no luck.
Could someone please point me in right direction to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Is it not possible to make the number of days passed to `date_add` a number column? That way you wouldn't need to evaluate the column dynamically. And for `salary`, why not simply `df.withColumn("salary", col('days') * 60)`?

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks, I did try passing number of days as a column, but was getting Column not iterable error, when calling `date_Add()`.
Also, the salary one here is more generic example, in real data the formula varies per row and numbers/columns involved in formula also varies.

Comment: Then I think it's going to be strongly advisable to redefine your data. I don't even think it's possible to dynamically evaluate these sql calls row-wise in any efficient way. I'd perhaps suggest you use non-sql expressions and use an RDD to process/evaluate them. But you should probably start by looking into making this data columns rather than expression strings (even if computing the result would involve a few `case` calls, that should probably still be better than alternatives).